# Object of trait in scala

Tags: scala, traits

during coursera course https://class.coursera.org/reactive-001/class I met such construction:

```
trait Generator[+T] {
  def generate: T
}
```

and usage:

```
val integers = new Generator[Int] {
  val rand = new java.util.Random
  def generate = rand.nextInt()
}
```

Why we can do this? Where I can find out more about it?

Comment: Think of a trait as a java **power** interface. In the second snippet, you're creating an anonymous class which implements the trait (or interface in javaland).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an anonymous subclass, as you can do it in Java.